# python string not contains any of list items from starting

Tags: python

I have an exclude list:

```
['topo', 'ecv', 'logs']
```

And I have a list of names:

```
['topo-116.qq.txt', 'sssecv-controls-11-11.txt']
```

I wanted to check in all names whether any of the exclude list contains in string from starting.

Comment: filter_func = lambda rpm: not any(x in rpm for x in tools)
rpms = [rpm for rpm in rpms if filter_func(rpm)]

This will check in the whole string.

Comment: Maybe `"topo-xxxx".startswith("topo")` will do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> exc = ['topo', 'ecv', 'logs']
>>> lst = ['topo-116.qq.txt', 'sssecv-controls-11-11.txt']

>>> print filter(lambda i: any([i.startswith(s) for s in exc]), lst)
['topo-116.qq.txt']
```